# SSRS gerating Error on isNothing function

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, division, divide-by-zero

I have the following equation - for basic division on a report to get percents.

ex_re_ct/p_ct = some value %

My equation needs to take `ex_re_ct` and divide it by `p_ct`. However in some cases `p_ct` has no value (it's NULL) and since i'm dealing with totals in the SSRS report I can't do this in SQL.

So i wrote the following equation --

```
=iif(   IsNothing((Sum(Fields!p_cnt.Value, "group1_v")))
        ,0
        ,((Sum(Fields!ex_re_ct.Value, "group1_v"))/(Sum(Fields!p_cnt.Value, "group1_v")))
    )
```

When i do this. (5 being a dummy value in the equation). It works without issue. But when i put the value in to divide it generates an #Error where there is null data.

```
=iif(   IsNothing((Sum(Fields!p_cnt.Value, "group1_v")))
        ,0
        ,((Sum(Fields!ex_re_ct.Value, "group1_v"))/5)
    )
```

please advise.

Comment: See comment #19190408

Comment: @DaleBurrell Sorry to be dense but how do I find comment #19190408

Comment: Just add `#19190408` to the URL :)

Comment: Okay, i saw the comment.  I still feel a little dense about the logic. If the divisor is = 0, then return 0, otherwise just do the division. Or if the divisor is Nothing (isnull) return 0 and if its not do the division. why do i need to have to Iifs.

Comment: `SSRS doesn't actually short circuit an IIF statement` means that SSRS evaluates both possible results even though it only uses one of them. Therefore you have to add protection in both results.

Comment: @DaleBurrell that is both limiting and frustrating, whats the point of all the checks. So what I have to say is if its zero, return zero. else check  again if its zero, and return zero and then if its not divide by the divisor

Comment: Agreed - scripting in SSRS can be very frustrating - if only it was in C# :)

Comment: @DaleBurrell so I did something like this and I still get an error `=iif(   IsNothing((Sum(Fields!p_cnt.Value, "group1_v")))
        ,0
        ,iif(IsNothing((Sum(Fields!p_cnt.Value, "venue"))),0,((Sum(Fields!ex_re_Ct.Value, "venue"))/(Sum(Fields!p_cnt.Value, "venue"))))`
    ) I'm not sure if its readable. But I still get an #error

Comment: You need the `IIF` on the divisor i.e. `Sum(Fields!p_cnt.Value, "venue"))` to return a valid divisor e.g. `IIf(IsNothing(Sum(Fields!p_cnt.Value, "venue")), 1, Sum(Fields!p_cnt.Value, "venue"))`

Comment: @DaleBurrell got it, and fixed it. Thank you for all your help.